# How to know whether a view controller is in stack. If it in stack it should be popped or else it should be pushed

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have 4 view controllers in a drop down.When I select a view controller from the drop down if the view controller is already in stack(i.e, already pushed) it should be popped or else pushed.

Comment: Post some code what have you done ?

Answer (score 1):

If the same instances of class "ViewController" can occur in navigationController this would work better

```
-(void)gotoViewController:(id )viewController
{
    if ([self.navigationController.viewControllers containsObject:viewController])
    {
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSInteger index = -1;
NSArray* arr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];
NSLog(@"View list=== %@",arr);
for(int i=0 ; i<[arr count] ; i++)
{
        if([[arr objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"ViewContollerName")])
        {
            index = i;
        }        
}
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[arr objectAtIndex:index] animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check the `navigationController` propterty on the viewcontroller you want to push or pop. This propterty is set if the vc is on a nav stack and `nil` if it's not. That would save you from iterating through all the vcs on the stack and make ugly class-tests.

Say you want to know if `theVC` is on the navigation controller stack, you could just do this:

```
if (theVC.navigationController == nil)
    //push the vc on the nav stack
else
    //pop the vc from the nav stack
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest better maintain a array. You only need to maintain the keyword of Navigated controller, this is how you could add object its logical not practical, so understand it accordingly

when retrieving check whether the object is there in the array, if yes pop it. And when poped remove it from the stack, else push it

Comment: What the fcuk is wrong with you moderators, when the resource is open/free how dare you could stop my account. THe moderator over here are like big fool with no brain or even if they have i guess its the hidden property is set to TRUE.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
UIViewController *currentView = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
currentView = [navigationController.visibleViewController retain];
if (![currentView isMemberOfClass:[YourViewController class]])
{
    //push
}

else
{
    //pop
}
[currentView release];
```

Note: Adjust if you are using ARC.

Make sure you reference the correct navigationController

Comment: That would only work, if the vc in questions was on top of the nav stack. Plus, the first line is not only useless, but also a memory leak in non-ARC projects.

Comment: @Tobi, yes I did make that assumption. Could you please explain why the first line is a memory leak?

Comment: You're allocating a `UIViewController` and saving a pointer to it in `currentView` in the first line. In the second line, you're overwriting said pointer, so you loose any reference to the `UIViewController` allocated in the first line and thus won't be able to release it at all.